# Ubuntu 15.04 does not shutdown properly

Tags: shutdown, 15.04, reboot, acpi

I recently installed Ubuntu 15.04 it works nicely but id does not shut down. If I manage to press delete key (it freezes quick) while it shut down it says this:

```
starting version 219
error:/dev/sdf: No medium found
error:/dev/sdd: No medium found
error:/dev/sde: No medium found
error:/dev/sdc: No medium found
error:/dev/sde: No medium found
error:/dev/sdd: No medium found
error:/dev/sdc: No medium found
error:/dev/sdf: No medium found
[ OK ] Started Light Display Manager.
[ OK ] Started ACPI even daemon.
Starting ACPI event daemon...
[ 94.225286] reboot: power down
```

and it freezes.

Could someone please help me fix this? If I can't fix it is it OK to force it to shut down? My motherboard is [Elitegroup 945GCT-M2/1333 (V1.0A)](http://www.ecs.com.tw/ECSWebSite/Product/Product_Detail.aspx?CategoryID=1&DetailID=827&DetailName=Feature&MenuID=1&LanID=0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved with recent software updates and my PC's CMOS battery dying (and that resulted in reset of settings).

Comment: The issue came back somehow after I changed the boot order from BIOS. After updating it it again disappeared, hopefully it stays so.